# Converting and printing the module names of a process

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to print and save the module names of a process.

But when printing the char array I get something that looks like an address.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    MODULEENTRY32 me32;
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, L"Window Name");
    DWORD dwPID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwPID);

    HANDLE hModuleSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwPID);

    me32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
    Module32First(hModuleSnap, &me32);
    std::cout << me32.szModule << std::endl;

    do
    {
        std::cout << me32.szModule << std::endl; // important line

    } while (Module32Next(hModuleSnap, &me32));

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this in my case was `00AFF53C` for every module.

`me32.szModule` holds the name of the module as a char array.

Microsoft used the following in [their example](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/ToolHelp/traversing-the-module-list) to convert and print the module name:

`_tprintf( TEXT("\n\n     MODULE NAME:     %s"), me32.szModule );`

But I think you can only use this to print the string.

So how do I convert and save the string in `me32`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project is being compiled with `UNICODE` defined (as evident by you being able to pass a wide string to `FindWindow()`).  That causes `Module32(First|Next)` to map to `Module32(First|Next)W`, and `MODULEENTRY32` to map to `MODULEENTRY32W` (and `FindWindow()` to map to `FindWindowW()`).  Thus, the `szModule` field is a `wchar_t[]` array instead of a `char[]` array, like you are expecting.  `std::cout` does not have an overload of `operator<<` for `wchar_t` data, only `char` data, but it has an overload for `void*`, and a fixed array decays into a pointer that can then be assigned to `void*`.  That is why your code is printing out the string data as a memory address - you are printing out the *address* of the `szModule` field rather than its *content*.

You need to either:

- use `std::wcout` instead, and preferably also explicitly use the `W` version of the API functions to match:

  ```cpp
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <TlHelp32.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>

  int main() {

      MODULEENTRY32W me32;
      HWND hwnd = FindWindowW(0, L"Window Name");
      DWORD dwPID;
      GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwPID);

      HANDLE hModuleSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwPID);

      me32.dwSize = sizeof(me32);
      if (Module32FirstW(hModuleSnap, &me32))
      {
          do
          {
              std::wstring moduleName = me32.szModule;
              std::wcout << moduleName << std::endl; // important line
          }
          while (Module32NextW(hModuleSnap, &me32));
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```
- explicitly use the `A` version of the API functions to match your use of `std::cout`:

  ```cpp
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <TlHelp32.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>

  int main() {

      MODULEENTRY32A me32;
      HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, L"Window Name");
      DWORD dwPID;
      GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwPID);

      HANDLE hModuleSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwPID);

      me32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32A);
      if (Module32FirstA(hModuleSnap, &me32))
      {
          do
          {
              std::string moduleName = me32.szModule;
              std::cout << moduleName << std::endl; // important line
          }
          while (Module32NextA(hModuleSnap, &me32));
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`_tprintf()` is a `typedef` for `wprintf()` if `_UNICODE` is defined, according to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l?view=vs-2019).

Take a look at [`std::wcout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout).